# Avahi add second hostname

Tags: avahi, mdns

Is it possible to let Avahi announce another hostname for the same machine?

I know it is meant to announce 'services', but usual clients like eg. browsers lack Avahi service support and rely on name resolution. Thus I would like to mark certain services by host names like `my_fileserver.local`, `my_tools.local` and so on. I may move around certain services on my machines then, and have the browser accessing the right machine for some service.

Answer (score 2):

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775233/how-to-route-all-subdomains-to-a-single-host-using-mdns) sounds like what you're looking for.

Sounds like a kluge to me. I would either setup DNS internally, or if you have a router/switch, make use of it's ability to perform DNS for your internal lan.

[Good DNS Server howto to start with](http://web.archive.org/web/20130404171747/http://computernetworkingnotes.com/linux-network-administrations/dns-server.html).

Comment: But as far as I understand DNS always works in a centralised fashion, one or more DNS servers assigning names to the IP adresses. With DHCP, those are not always fixed so it would need to assign names to MAC addresses I think. With Avahi/Zeroconf, the machines are able to carry their names by themselves.

Comment: DHCP & DNS can be configured so that they work together. When the DHCP server hands out new IPs it can automatically update the DNS server with this new information. This [tutorial](http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-setup-dhcp-server-and-dynamic-dns-with-bind-in-debian.html) shows how to do dynamic dns (i.e. DHCP server updates DNS).

Comment: There is still the problem that many simple routers do not provide DNS or do not assign their own DNS address to the DHCP clients - those then use some internet-hosted DNS which has no idea of the local names of course.